# Jump of an infinite step function

Tags: real-analysis

**Example**: Let $0<x$ be real and let $n$ be natural numbers. Consider the sequence $\left\{ x^n  \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Whenever $0<x<1$ one finds $x^n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. When $x=1$ one finds $x^n\to 1$, and whenever $1<x$ one finds $x^n\to\infty$. So, the sequence $\left\{ x^n  \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ tends to $0$, $1$ or $\infty$ for positive $x$. We notice here that $x^n$ tends to $1$ at the jump, between values $0$ and $\infty$. This result can be summarized as follows.

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n
=
\begin{cases}
0\text{, }0<x<1\\
1\text{, }x=1\\
\infty\text{, }1<x
\end{cases}
$$

**Question**: Let $a_n(x)$ be strictly positive smooth real function. As $n\to\infty$, let $a_n(x)\to 0$ for $0<x<1$, and $a_n(x)\to \infty$ for $1<x$. Define number $L$ by $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n(1)$. Then $0<L<\infty$.

So, in other words, is it true that for all such $a_n(x)$ the magnitude at the jump is strictly positive finite? Or are there sequences $\left\{ a_n(x)  \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $L=0$ or $L=\infty$?

Comment: For $L=0$ you can take $a_n(x) = n(x-1)\chi_{(1, \infty)}$

Comment: @stackex33 Yes, but are there cases with $L=0$ at all?

Comment: Do you mean $L=\infty$? because I gave an example for $L=0$. Also, I think you want $a_n$ to be continuous. When not continuous, $a_n(x) = n\chi_{[1, \infty)}$ is an example for $L=\infty$.

Comment: @stackex33 (A) I'd like $a_n(x)$ strictly positive. Will edit the question appropriately. (B) Yes, is there an example for $L=\infty$?

Comment: @stackex33 Indeed, thanks, yes, continuous, or even smooth.

Comment: @stackex33 Seems the minimal assumption has to be that $a$s are smooth. I edited the question. Yes, your answer holds for $a$ continuous. It fails for $a$ smooth though. Is there an example for $a_n(x)$ smooth?

Comment: Continuous case. For $L=\infty$: Take an to be the function taking $1/n$ on $[0,1−1/n]$ and beyond that the line passing through $(1−1/n,1/n)$ and $(1,n)$.

For $L=0$: Take an to be $1/n$ on $[0,1]$ and beyond $1$, a line with slope $n$ passing through $(1,1/n)$. I think it should be possible to smooth this out in some way.

Comment: [Mollifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)+monotone-ness might give a smooth sequence, although the rapid rise of $a_n$ to the right of $1$ could change the limits for $x<1$.

Comment: @stackex33 The question can be proven by non-standard methods. One naturally wonders if the standard analysis can produce the same result. I expected a ready standard result. It seems thus far that the question is open in the standard setting. By non-standard analysis I mean the use of infinitesimals, numbers that do not belong to the standard set of real numbers, but are in-between reals. In this non-standard setting, continuity over the range of $x$ stands even at the jump, so one can find any real magnitude in any neighborhood of the jump. The lack of standard result seems surprising!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a constant on $[0, 1/n]$, take a line from $(1/n, 1/n)$ to $(-1, 0)$ and then for $x<-1$, keep all $a_n=0$ (do the same thing for the other family of functions). This way the $a_n$ form a family of continuous functions.

Now, fix some integer $n\geq 2$. Since $a_n$ is continuous on $[-2n, 2n]$, there is a polynomial (by Weierstrass approximation) $p_n$ approximating $a_n$ uniformly within $\epsilon_n$ where $\epsilon_n$ is chosen so that $a_n-\epsilon_n>0$ for $x>0$ (exists because $a_n$ is non zero on the positive side).

This way, $p_n>0$ when $x>0$. Next, take a smooth (positive) bump function $\phi_n$ attaining $1$ on $[-n, n]$ with support in $[-2n, 2n]$ and consider $p_n\phi_n$. This is a smooth function and equal to $p_n$ on $[-n, n]$, however it is $0$ for large $|x|$.

It is clear that the sequence $p_n\phi_n$ is smooth, nonnegative on $x\geq 0$ and has the required limits (note that the $\epsilon_n$ converge to $0$). To obtain strictly positive functions, simply consider $p_n\phi_n+1/n$.

This seems to work. Could you elaborate your comment regarding non standard analysis, I am ignorant on the subject.

Comment: @anonymous what do you think of this answer?

Comment: hi, accepted answer. I kept it open just in case someone else chimes in. In nonstandard analysis there are infinitesimals between reals. A continuous function with right and left limits $0$ and $r>0$ actually has limits in the infinitesimal region around the jump. A closer analysis demonstrates that in there, the function remains continuous. I cannot find any reference, but you can probably construct your own theory about it, which agrees with standard mathematics on real numbers.